# How to enable xcode 7 UI testing in existing ios Test project

Tags: xcode, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

In an existing ios app and project, how do I enable an existing test target and classes to support UI testing and the record UI test button?

I can add a new test target and I'll see the record button if I do that, but what if I wanted to add some UI testing functions to an existing test class and target?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UI Testing is in a separate target from normal unit test cases, so you can't just add UI testing to you existing test cases.

Answer (score 0):

You should use new UI test target to add/execute your ui tests for clean build and maintenance purpose.However, assuming you are trying to call XCUI* APIs in your unit test classes and enable UI recording with unit test target, I see couple of issues cropping up there,

1. If you are using swift2 for unit testing and including your main app modules using `@testable import {module}`, when you call XCUI* menthods from this testcase, swift will throw an error

> Module {module} was not compiled for testing

Since UI test run as separate process, it can't load you app code    dependencies.

2. Since XCUI* api depends on Obj-C libraries, invoking UI test methods would expect you to include Objective-C Bridging Header file in your unit test target. It would not error out but it pollutes your target.
3. I also verified that you need to add your test case file to UI test target in order to enable UI test recording button.

There are other benefits of running UI tests as a separate target, e.g flexibility of specifying the target to only run unit test or UI test from the command line tools and ease of maintaining clean state for UI tests execution.